# how to search in a list and if not found choose the nearest highest value elixir

Tags: elixir

I have these 2 lists.

one list is:

```
[~U[2020-05-20 11:00:00.123456Z], ~U[2020-05-20 11:20:00.123456Z],
 ~U[2020-05-20 11:40:00.123456Z]]
```

and 2nd list is:

```
["00_02_000.jpg", "00_06_000.jpg", "00_14_000.jpg", "00_18_000.jpg",
 "00_22_000.jpg", "00_30_000.jpg", "00_34_000.jpg", "00_38_000.jpg",
 "00_42_000.jpg", "00_46_000.jpg", "00_54_000.jpg", "00_58_000.jpg",
 "01_02_000.jpg", "01_10_000.jpg", "01_14_000.jpg", "01_18_000.jpg",
 "01_22_000.jpg", "01_30_000.jpg", "01_34_000.jpg", "01_38_000.jpg",
 "01_42_000.jpg", "01_50_000.jpg", "01_54_000.jpg", "01_58_000.jpg",
 "02_02_000.jpg", "02_06_000.jpg", "02_25_000.jpg", "02_29_000.jpg",
 "02_33_000.jpg", "02_41_000.jpg", "02_45_000.jpg", "02_49_000.jpg",
 "02_53_000.jpg", "03_01_000.jpg", "03_05_000.jpg", "03_09_000.jpg",
 "03_13_000.jpg", "03_21_000.jpg", "03_25_000.jpg", "03_29_000.jpg",
 "03_33_000.jpg", "03_41_000.jpg", "03_45_000.jpg", "03_49_000.jpg",
 "03_53_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg", "04_05_000.jpg", "04_09_000.jpg",
 "04_13_000.jpg", "04_21_000.jpg", ...]
```

now, I first want to convert the first list into.

```
["00_00_000.jpg", "20_00_000.jpg", "40_00_000.jpg"]
```

which is done through strftime.

and then I want to create a 3rd list. of size 3, which either includes only

```
["00_00_000.jpg", "20_00_000.jpg", "40_00_000.jpg"]
```

if it's present in the 2nd list.

if not present in the second list then choose the very next value of it. example

in the above list, there is no `00_00_000.jpg` So I want to choose `00_02_000.jpg` same as for `20_00_000.jpg`

Update: the resulting list either should be this

```
["00_00_000.jpg", "20_00_000.jpg", "40_00_000.jpg"]
```

of the very nest values of these 3. such

in values. the next value for `"00_00_000.jpg"` is `"00_02_000.jpg"` same as if `20_00_000.jpg` dont exist the next of this can be `21_00_000.jpg`

Update:

while having values as

```
values =
["00_08_000.jpg", "00_18_000.jpg", "00_28_000.jpg", "00_38_000.jpg",
 "00_48_000.jpg", "00_58_000.jpg", "01_08_000.jpg", "01_18_000.jpg",
 "01_28_000.jpg", "01_38_000.jpg", "01_48_000.jpg", "01_58_000.jpg",
 "02_08_000.jpg", "02_18_000.jpg", "02_28_000.jpg", "02_38_000.jpg",
 "02_48_000.jpg", "02_58_000.jpg", "03_08_000.jpg", "03_18_000.jpg",
 "03_28_000.jpg", "03_38_000.jpg", "03_48_000.jpg", "03_58_000.jpg",
 "04_08_000.jpg", "04_18_000.jpg", "04_28_000.jpg", "04_38_000.jpg",
 "04_48_000.jpg", "04_58_000.jpg", "05_08_000.jpg", "05_18_000.jpg",
 "05_28_000.jpg", "05_38_000.jpg", "05_48_000.jpg", "05_58_000.jpg",
 "06_08_000.jpg", "06_18_000.jpg", "06_28_000.jpg", "06_38_000.jpg",
 "06_48_000.jpg", "06_58_000.jpg", "07_08_000.jpg", "07_18_000.jpg",
 "07_28_000.jpg", "07_38_000.jpg", "07_48_000.jpg", "07_58_000.jpg",
 "08_08_000.jpg", "08_18_000.jpg", "08_28_000.jpg", "08_38_000.jpg",
 "08_48_000.jpg", "08_58_000.jpg", "09_08_000.jpg", "09_18_000.jpg",
 "09_28_000.jpg", "09_38_000.jpg", "09_48_000.jpg", "09_58_000.jpg",
 "10_08_000.jpg", "10_18_000.jpg", "10_28_000.jpg", "10_38_000.jpg",
 "10_48_000.jpg", "10_58_000.jpg", "11_08_000.jpg", "11_18_000.jpg",
 "11_28_000.jpg", "11_38_000.jpg", "11_48_000.jpg", "11_58_000.jpg",
 "12_08_000.jpg", "12_18_000.jpg", "12_28_000.jpg", "12_38_000.jpg",
 "12_48_000.jpg", "12_58_000.jpg", "13_08_000.jpg", "13_18_000.jpg",
 "13_28_000.jpg", "13_38_000.jpg", "13_48_000.jpg", "13_58_000.jpg",
 "14_08_000.jpg", "14_18_000.jpg", "14_28_000.jpg", "14_38_000.jpg",
 "14_48_000.jpg", "14_58_000.jpg", "15_08_000.jpg", "15_18_000.jpg",
 "15_28_000.jpg", "15_38_000.jpg", "15_48_000.jpg", "15_58_000.jpg",
 "16_08_000.jpg", "16_18_000.jpg", "16_28_000.jpg", "16_38_000.jpg",
 "16_48_000.jpg", "16_58_000.jpg", "17_08_000.jpg", "17_18_000.jpg",
 "17_28_000.jpg", "17_38_000.jpg", "17_48_000.jpg", "17_58_000.jpg",
 "18_08_000.jpg", "18_18_000.jpg", "18_28_000.jpg", "18_38_000.jpg",
 "18_48_000.jpg", "18_58_000.jpg", "19_08_000.jpg", "19_18_000.jpg",
 "19_28_000.jpg", "19_38_000.jpg", "19_48_000.jpg", "19_58_000.jpg",
 "20_08_000.jpg", "20_18_000.jpg", "20_28_000.jpg", "20_38_000.jpg",
 "20_48_000.jpg", "20_58_000.jpg", "21_08_000.jpg", "21_18_000.jpg",
 "21_28_000.jpg", "21_38_000.jpg", "21_48_000.jpg", "21_58_000.jpg",
 "22_08_000.jpg", "22_18_000.jpg", "22_28_000.jpg", "22_38_000.jpg",
 "22_48_000.jpg", "22_58_000.jpg", "23_08_000.jpg", "23_18_000.jpg",
 "23_28_000.jpg", "23_38_000.jpg", "23_48_000.jpg", "23_58_000.jpg",
 "24_08_000.jpg", "24_18_000.jpg", "24_28_000.jpg", "24_38_000.jpg",
 "24_48_000.jpg", "24_58_000.jpg", "25_08_000.jpg", "25_18_000.jpg",
 "25_28_000.jpg", "25_38_000.jpg", "25_48_000.jpg", "25_58_000.jpg",
 "26_08_000.jpg", "26_18_000.jpg", "26_28_000.jpg", "26_38_000.jpg",
 "26_48_000.jpg", "26_58_000.jpg", "27_08_000.jpg", "27_18_000.jpg",
 "27_28_000.jpg", "27_38_000.jpg", "27_48_000.jpg", "27_58_000.jpg",
 "28_08_000.jpg", "28_18_000.jpg", "28_28_000.jpg", "28_38_000.jpg",
 "28_48_000.jpg", "28_58_000.jpg", "29_08_000.jpg", "29_18_000.jpg",
 "29_28_000.jpg", "29_38_000.jpg", "29_48_000.jpg", "29_58_000.jpg",
 "30_08_000.jpg", "30_18_000.jpg", "30_28_000.jpg", "30_38_000.jpg",
 "30_48_000.jpg", "30_58_000.jpg", "31_08_000.jpg", "31_18_000.jpg",
 "31_28_000.jpg", "31_38_000.jpg", "31_48_000.jpg", "31_58_000.jpg",
 "32_08_000.jpg", "32_18_000.jpg", "32_28_000.jpg", "32_38_000.jpg",
 "32_48_000.jpg", "32_58_000.jpg", "33_08_000.jpg", "33_18_000.jpg",
 "33_28_000.jpg", "33_38_000.jpg", "33_48_000.jpg", "33_58_000.jpg",
 "34_08_000.jpg", "34_18_000.jpg", "34_28_000.jpg", "34_38_000.jpg",
 "34_48_000.jpg", "34_58_000.jpg", "35_08_000.jpg", "35_18_000.jpg", 
 "35_28_000.jpg", "35_38_000.jpg", "35_48_000.jpg", "35_58_000.jpg",
 "36_08_000.jpg", "36_18_000.jpg", "36_28_000.jpg", "36_38_000.jpg",
 "36_48_000.jpg", "36_58_000.jpg", "37_08_000.jpg", "37_18_000.jpg",
 "37_28_000.jpg", "37_38_000.jpg", "37_48_000.jpg", "37_58_000.jpg",
 "38_08_000.jpg", "38_18_000.jpg", "38_28_000.jpg", "38_38_000.jpg",
 "38_48_000.jpg", "38_58_000.jpg", "39_08_000.jpg", "39_18_000.jpg",
 "39_28_000.jpg", "39_38_000.jpg", "39_48_000.jpg", "39_58_000.jpg",
 "40_08_000.jpg", "40_18_000.jpg", "40_28_000.jpg", "40_38_000.jpg",
 "40_48_000.jpg", "40_58_000.jpg", "41_08_000.jpg", "41_18_000.jpg",
 "41_28_000.jpg", "41_38_000.jpg", "41_48_000.jpg", "41_58_000.jpg",
 "42_08_000.jpg", "42_18_000.jpg", "42_28_000.jpg", "42_38_000.jpg",
 "42_48_000.jpg", "42_58_000.jpg", "43_08_000.jpg", "43_18_000.jpg",
 "43_28_000.jpg", "43_38_000.jpg", "43_48_000.jpg", "43_58_000.jpg",
 "44_08_000.jpg", "44_18_000.jpg", "44_28_000.jpg", "44_38_000.jpg",
 "44_48_000.jpg", "44_58_000.jpg", "45_08_000.jpg", "45_18_000.jpg",
 "45_28_000.jpg", "45_38_000.jpg", "45_48_000.jpg", "45_58_000.jpg",
 "46_08_000.jpg", "46_18_000.jpg", "46_28_000.jpg", "46_38_000.jpg",
 "46_48_000.jpg", "46_58_000.jpg", "47_08_000.jpg", "47_18_000.jpg",
 "47_28_000.jpg", "47_38_000.jpg", "47_48_000.jpg", "47_58_000.jpg",
 "48_08_000.jpg", "48_18_000.jpg", "48_28_000.jpg", "48_38_000.jpg",
 "48_48_000.jpg", "48_58_000.jpg", "49_08_000.jpg", "49_18_000.jpg",
 "49_28_000.jpg", "49_38_000.jpg", "49_48_000.jpg", "49_58_000.jpg",
 "50_08_000.jpg", "50_18_000.jpg", "50_28_000.jpg", "50_38_000.jpg",
 "50_48_000.jpg", "50_58_000.jpg", "51_08_000.jpg", "51_18_000.jpg",
 "51_28_000.jpg", "51_38_000.jpg", "51_48_000.jpg", "51_58_000.jpg",
 "52_08_000.jpg", "52_18_000.jpg", "52_28_000.jpg", "52_38_000.jpg",
 "52_48_000.jpg", "52_58_000.jpg", "53_08_000.jpg", "53_18_000.jpg",
 "53_28_000.jpg", "53_38_000.jpg", "53_48_000.jpg", "53_58_000.jpg",
 "54_08_000.jpg", "54_18_000.jpg", "54_28_000.jpg", "54_38_000.jpg",
 "54_48_000.jpg", "54_58_000.jpg", "55_08_000.jpg", "55_18_000.jpg",
 "55_28_000.jpg", "55_38_000.jpg", "55_48_000.jpg", "55_58_000.jpg",
 "56_08_000.jpg", "56_18_000.jpg", "56_28_000.jpg", "56_38_000.jpg",
 "56_48_000.jpg", "56_58_000.jpg", "57_08_000.jpg", "57_18_000.jpg",
 "57_28_000.jpg", "57_38_000.jpg", "57_48_000.jpg", "57_58_000.jpg",
 "58_08_000.jpg", "58_18_000.jpg", "58_28_000.jpg", "58_38_000.jpg",
 "58_48_000.jpg", "58_58_000.jpg", "59_08_000.jpg", "59_18_000.jpg",
 "59_28_000.jpg", "59_38_000.jpg", "59_48_000.jpg", "59_58_000.jpg"]
```

and list as

```
list =
["24_00_000.jpg", "24_01_000.jpg", "24_02_000.jpg", "24_03_000.jpg",
 "24_04_000.jpg", "24_05_000.jpg", "24_06_000.jpg", "24_07_000.jpg",
 "24_08_000.jpg", "24_09_000.jpg", "24_10_000.jpg", "24_11_000.jpg",
 "24_12_000.jpg", "24_13_000.jpg", "24_14_000.jpg", "24_15_000.jpg",
 "24_16_000.jpg", "24_17_000.jpg", "24_18_000.jpg", "24_19_000.jpg",
 "24_20_000.jpg", "24_21_000.jpg", "24_22_000.jpg", "24_23_000.jpg",
 "24_24_000.jpg", "24_25_000.jpg", "24_26_000.jpg", "24_27_000.jpg",
 "24_28_000.jpg", "24_29_000.jpg", "24_30_000.jpg", "24_31_000.jpg",
 "24_32_000.jpg", "24_33_000.jpg", "24_34_000.jpg", "24_35_000.jpg",
 "24_36_000.jpg", "24_37_000.jpg", "24_38_000.jpg", "24_39_000.jpg",
 "24_40_000.jpg", "24_41_000.jpg", "24_42_000.jpg", "24_43_000.jpg",
 "24_44_000.jpg", "24_45_000.jpg", "24_46_000.jpg", "24_47_000.jpg",
 "24_48_000.jpg", "24_49_000.jpg", "24_50_000.jpg", "24_51_000.jpg",
 "24_52_000.jpg", "24_53_000.jpg", "24_54_000.jpg", "24_55_000.jpg",
 "24_56_000.jpg", "24_57_000.jpg", "24_58_000.jpg", "24_59_000.jpg",
 "25_00_000.jpg", "25_01_000.jpg", "25_02_000.jpg", "25_03_000.jpg",
 "25_04_000.jpg", "25_05_000.jpg", "25_06_000.jpg", "25_07_000.jpg",
 "25_08_000.jpg", "25_09_000.jpg", "25_10_000.jpg", "25_11_000.jpg",
 "25_12_000.jpg", "25_13_000.jpg", "25_14_000.jpg", "25_15_000.jpg",
 "25_16_000.jpg", "25_17_000.jpg", "25_18_000.jpg", "25_19_000.jpg",
 "25_20_000.jpg", "25_21_000.jpg", "25_22_000.jpg", "25_23_000.jpg",
 "25_24_000.jpg", "25_25_000.jpg", "25_26_000.jpg", "25_27_000.jpg",
 "25_28_000.jpg", "25_29_000.jpg", "25_30_000.jpg", "25_31_000.jpg",
 "25_32_000.jpg", "25_33_000.jpg", "25_34_000.jpg", "25_35_000.jpg",
 "25_36_000.jpg", "25_37_000.jpg", "25_38_000.jpg", "25_39_000.jpg",
 "25_40_000.jpg", "25_41_000.jpg", "25_42_000.jpg", "25_43_000.jpg",
 "25_44_000.jpg", "25_45_000.jpg", "25_46_000.jpg", "25_47_000.jpg",
 "25_48_000.jpg", "25_49_000.jpg", "25_50_000.jpg", "25_51_000.jpg",
 "25_52_000.jpg", "25_53_000.jpg", "25_54_000.jpg", "25_55_000.jpg",
 "25_56_000.jpg", "25_57_000.jpg", "25_58_000.jpg", "25_59_000.jpg",
 "26_00_000.jpg"]
```

the below solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way would be to reduce both the long list *and* the short list simultaneously.

```rb
values =
["00_02_000.jpg", "00_06_000.jpg", "00_14_000.jpg", "00_18_000.jpg",
 "00_22_000.jpg", "00_30_000.jpg", "00_34_000.jpg", "00_38_000.jpg",
 "00_42_000.jpg", "00_46_000.jpg", "00_54_000.jpg", "00_58_000.jpg",
 "01_02_000.jpg", "01_10_000.jpg", "01_14_000.jpg", "01_18_000.jpg",
 "01_22_000.jpg", "01_30_000.jpg", "01_34_000.jpg", "01_38_000.jpg",
 "01_42_000.jpg", "01_50_000.jpg", "01_54_000.jpg", "01_58_000.jpg",
 "02_02_000.jpg", "02_06_000.jpg", "02_25_000.jpg", "02_29_000.jpg",
 "02_33_000.jpg", "02_41_000.jpg", "02_45_000.jpg", "02_49_000.jpg",
 "02_53_000.jpg", "03_01_000.jpg", "03_05_000.jpg", "03_09_000.jpg",
 "03_13_000.jpg", "03_21_000.jpg", "03_25_000.jpg", "03_29_000.jpg",
 "03_33_000.jpg", "03_41_000.jpg", "03_45_000.jpg", "03_49_000.jpg",
 "03_53_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg", "04_05_000.jpg", "04_09_000.jpg",
 "04_13_000.jpg", "04_21_000.jpg"]

list = Enum.sort(["00_00_000.jpg", "02_01_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg"])

values
|> Enum.reduce_while({list, []}, fn
  _, {[], acc} -> {:halt, acc}
  e, {[h|t], acc} ->
    {:cont, 
      if(String.split(e, ~w[_ .]) < String.split(h, ~w[_ .]),
        do: {[h|t], acc},
        else: {t, [e | acc]})
    }
end)
|> Enum.reverse()

#⇒ ["00_02_000.jpg", "02_02_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg"]
```

Basically, here we walk through the long list, and once we meet the value that is greater or equal to the current head in the short list, we both *inject it to the accumulator* and *remove from the short list*.

---

If the performance is not critical, the solution with mapping short list to the first found in the long list would be probably easier to read and support.

```rb
Enum.map(list, fn e ->
  Enum.find(values,
    &(String.split(e, ~w[_ .]) <= String.split(&1, ~w[_ .])))
end)
#⇒ ["00_02_000.jpg", "02_02_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg"]
```

Comment: I think you have mistaken the 2nd list? which is of size 3? its `["00_00_000.jpg", "20_00_000.jpg", "40_00_000.jpg"]`
and I want to get either the same or the very next value from the each. such as

in long list, next value from `00_00_000.jpg` is `00_02_000.jpg`

Comment: I am not sure I follow. `["00_02_000.jpg"|_]` is indeed there in both outcomes. I changed the second and the third value to make the long list shorter for the sake of the example.

Comment: `list = Enum.sort(["00_00_000.jpg", "02_01_000.jpg", "04_01_000.jpg"])` this is wrong, not the one list mentioned in question :)

Comment: **I changed the second and the third value to make the long list shorter for the sake of the example.** How do you suppose me to test it with `40_` if this data is even not given in the question? Please, check that both snippets I provided perfectly work on your data before complaining.

Comment: Sory to bother you but it some times gives a tuple before reversing it such as `["30_04_000.jpg", "00_01_000.jpg"]` instead of this, it gives this `{["30_00_000.jpg"], ["00_00_000.jpg"]}`

Comment: That means the long list does not have a value satisfying the condition, it gets exhausted and returns a tuple of what it gained and what not. Check docs for reduce_while/3.

Comment: The latter solution would give nils there.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the data set to tell you what I was trying to say, the exact same solution and the above data set, the solution won't work. it ends at `44_08_000.jpg` , and as per the solution it should stop at `26_00_000.jpg`